# Gradle task don't run in all subprojects

Tags: gradle, multi-project, gradle-task

I have the following multi-module project structure.

```
Root project 'reports-be'
+--- Project ':auth'
+--- Project ':builder'
|    +--- Project ':builder:base'
|    \--- Project ':builder:reporting'
\--- Project ':common'
```

When I run `build` task for */builder* subproject and I expect that `build` task will be executed for all subprojects (for `:builder:base` and `:builder:reporting`).

```
gradle clean :builder:build
```

But gradle execute `build` task only for subproject `:builder`.
According [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html) `build` task should be completed for all subprojects.

Why doesn't it happen?

P.S. I found that the command `gradle -p builder clean build` works as I expected. But I really don't understand what is wrong with first mentioned gradle task.

P.S.S. I have `build.gradle` in every subproject and my `settings.gradle` looks like

```
rootProject.name = 'reports-be'
include 'common'
include 'builder'
include 'auth'
include 'builder:base'
include 'builder:reporting'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:builder:build` is a qualified task name of the task `build` in the project `:builder`, so only this one task (and its dependencies) will be executed. The execution in all (sub-)projects is only possible for unqualified task names as `build`. You may switch to the `builder` directory and run `gradle build` from there, however this approach won't work if you want to run `clean` for all projects in the same invocation and it's kind of ugly when using the wrapper (`gradlew`). As far as I know, there is no direct solution for your use case.

If I get you right, the `:builder` project is just a dummy project for organization purposes and does not contain any actual sources or anything else to build. In this case, you may solve your problems using task dependencies inside `builder/build.gradle`:

```
task build {
    dependsOn ':builder:base:build', ':builder:reporting:build'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It is what I expect to know!
Put my 2 cents to your explanation.
For Gradle 6.3 correct command:
```build {
    dependsOn ':builder:base:build', ':builder:reporting:build'
}```

Comment: Also It works to switch directory and run ```gradle clean build``` (not `gradlew`)

Comment: Yes, but only if `gradle` is installed on the machine. If using the wrapper, this is often not provided.

Comment: And you can only refer to the task `build` without creating it (like in your example), if it already exists, probably because you applied the `java` plugin.

Comment: Thank you one more time. You are absolutly right, I have installed `gradle` on my machine and applied `java` plugin to my project :)

Answer (score 1):

Three possible solutions which I found:

1.
`gradle -p builder clean build`

2:

```
cd ./builder
gradle clean build
```

3. Add modification for *builder/build.gradle* (work for Gradle 6.3):

```
build {
    dependsOn ':builder:base:build', ':builder:reporting:build'
}
```

And run `gradle clean build` from root project directory.
Thank you for this solution [Lukas Korfer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61917108/3454339)